# Strange font-style / font-weight on CPT list columns screen

Tags: wp-list-table

As you can see below, for some reason the "Author" column displays extremely strange (like non-anti aliased) in Chrome. I added the snippet from the dev tools bar to show that I can't see any difference. Do you know why this happens?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of this CSS rule that is generated in load-styles.php:

```
.widefat thead th:last-of-type {
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
    -khtml-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

I'm not sure why this is here. To remove it, you should make a [custom admin theme plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes) to overwrite that CSS rule.

First create a folder in your /wp-content/plugins/ directory named wpse_34959 (or whatever plugin name you want). In that folder, create wpse_34959.php with the following contents:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Admin Theme
Plugin URI: http://yoursite.com
Description: My WordPress Admin Theme - Upload and Activate.
Author: Your Name
Version: 1.0
*/

function my_admin_head() {
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' .plugins_url('wp-admin.css', __FILE__). '">';
}

add_action('admin_head', 'my_admin_head');

?>
```

In that same plugin directory, create a file named wp-admin.css with the following contents:

```
.widefat thead th:last-of-type {
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
    -khtml-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}
```

Activate the plugin via the WordPress Admin interface, and those styles that is causing that behavior should now be overridden.

Comment: I could also simply write a plugin that echos the style in admin_head. Anyway: It wasn't about how to write a plugin, but +1 for the extensive answer and narrowing it down to the `border-top-right-radius: 3px;` definition. If I'd write a plugin, I'd also add `$browser = get_browser(); if ( 'Chrome' === $browser['browser'] ) echo <style>...` as this works fine in for e.g. FF.